# Unable to click on radio buttons while executing script-UFT tool

Tags: qtp, hp-uft, uft-api

I am unable to click on radio button while executing script by using `UFT/QTP` tool. Below is my code:

```
Browser("Welcome!").Page("Welcome!_9").WebList("pickupOnePauId").Select "Aisha Shop"
Browser("Welcome!").Page("Welcome!_9").WebRadioGroup("pdaId_Mon").Select "#3"
Browser("Welcome!").Page("Welcome!_9").WebRadioGroup("pdaId_Tue").Select "#3"
```

Comment: Can someone please guide me here?

Comment: what is the exception?

Answer (score 1):

You need to select the what is mentioned in the value property of the input tag for that radio element.

For Example

if your html tag is like this

```
<input name="priceOrder" class="custom-control-input priceOrderAsc" id="priceOrderDes" type="radio" value="des">
```

then your UFT object selection should be

```
Browser("Hotels Results").Page("Hotels Results").WebRadioGroup("high to low").Select "acs"
```

You can also specify the index for the select value using "#index" as you have done, but index starts with 0, which means as per your code you are trying to select 4th radio button in that radio group

If you paste your html markup for those dropdowns we can tell what needs to go in the select.